# How do i display a property in an object which is saved on local storage,using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

`{Msg:"blah", isDeleted:false, isCompleted:"false", id:1}`

I save this object to local storage, how to i get the msg property and display it on another component in react

I tried to get the item like this on the other component
`
{JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"))}

`

In which "todos" is the saved object,

`{Msg:"blah",

isDeleted:false,

isCompleted:"false",

id:1}`

Comment: And whats the issue? "*React can't render Objects*"?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just put `JSON.parse()` in JSX as this method returns an object and you can't render an object in React. First you have to store the parsed data in a variable or state, and then use that variable to render the properties from the parsed JSON data into the JSX.

```
const parsed = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));

return(
 <div className="App">
   {parsed.Msg}
 </div>
)
```